# I want to run a project from my localhost

Tags: java, apache

I'm following a textbook example and I need to run Apache and then open the file in my browser as http:localhost:0000/file

How do I know which number my local host is? The textbook says 9080 but I assume that's not universal.

Comment: It depends what port you ran Apache on.

Comment: By default port will be 8080. We can change it if needed.

Comment: What are you using to run apache? Usually the default is 8080, but it can differ if you have previously changed stuff.

Comment: nmap -sT -O localhost (if you are in a linux machine) will tell you info about ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the eclipse view "Servers" double click in Tomcat -> tab Overview and check the http port.

By default the port used is 8080.

In the tab modules you can check the path

by default:

http:localhost:8080/projectName

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using Apache Tomcat, the port where the server is listening is defined in the server.xml file (ApacheTomcatHome/conf/server.xml) in a line more or less like this one:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

This line defines the listening port as 8080 but you can change it just modifying the port and restarting the server.

To access the file you will have to deploy a web application (.war) and place at the following location the file you want to see:

ApacheTomcatHome/webapps/applicationName/file

In case your example is talking about Apache Web server the default port where the server is installed is 80. If you place your file at var/www/ then it will be accessible at http://localhost:80/file.

If you want/need to change the port, it can be done at httpd.conf (or apache2.conf) file modifying the line where it states Listen 80.